# PL/SQL Dynamic SQL : Table name not valid

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I'm currently learning PL/SQL. I need to create a PL/SQL block to create a backup of all my tables like this : myTable -> myTable_old.

Here's what I got right now :

```
DECLARE
Cursor c IS SELECT table_name 
            FROM user_tables 
            WHERE table_name NOT LIKE '%_old';
sql_slc VARCHAR2(200);
sql_drp VARCHAR2(200);
sql_crt VARCHAR2(200);
row_count NUMBER;
t_name user_tables.table_name%type;
t_backup_name user_tables.table_name%type;

BEGIN
    sql_drp := 'DROP TABLE :1 CASCADE';
    sql_crt := 'CREATE TABLE :1 AS SELECT * FROM :2';
    sql_slc := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_tables WHERE table_name = :1';
    OPEN c;
    LOOP
        FETCH c INTO t_name;
        EXIT WHEN (c%NOTFOUND);
        t_backup_name := t_name || '_old';
        dbms_output.put_line(t_name || ' ' || t_backup_name);
        
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_slc INTO row_count USING t_backup_name;
        IF row_count > 0 THEN
            dbms_output.put_line(t_backup_name || ' dropped');
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_drp USING t_backup_name;
        END IF;
        dbms_output.put_line(t_backup_name || ' created');
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_crt USING t_backup_name, t_name;
        COMMIT;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c;
END;
/
```

Here's the error :

```
OUVRAGE OUVRAGE_old
OUVRAGE_old created
DECLARE
*
ERROR on line 1 :
ORA-00903: table name not valid
ORA-06512: on line 29
```

I don't understand why this error is coming up, can someone help me ?

Comment: It might have failed because t_name's length was about 32 so, adding "_old" made it too long to be accepted by a database. (depends on db version)

Comment: The name of next table where it crashes is 'AUTEUR_OUVRAGE' which if added _old is still inferior to a VARCHAR2(30) in lenght... I still tried to change t_name and t_backup_name to VARCHAR2(30) and nothing changed.

Comment: I see it says error occured on line 29 but still try to comment out the first execute immediate statement and run the block again. Let's see where the error occurs

Comment: It crashes on the 2nd execute (drop) if row_count > 0 and every time on the 3rd one (create table).

Comment: Another test then. Replace the last "execute immediate" with the following 

begin
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_crt USING t_backup_name, t_name;
exception
  when others then
    dbms_output.put_line('t_backup_name: ' || t_backup_name || ' t_name: ' || t_name);
    return;
end;

Let's see what it outputs

Comment: Since the first table_name returned is 'OUVRAGE' it says 't_backup_name: OUVRAGE_OLD t_name: OUVRAGE'

Comment: I believe Aleksej got the right answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you can not use bind variables for table names; [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/dynamic-sql.html#GUID-4503110E-DF12-487E-B613-6890CC55B6CD):

> The database uses the values of bind variables exclusively and does
> not interpret their contents in any way.

You should edit your code to use concatenation instead:

```
DECLARE
  Cursor c IS SELECT table_name 
              FROM user_tables 
              WHERE table_name NOT LIKE '%_OLD';           /* OLD, upper case */  
  sql_slc VARCHAR2(200);
  --sql_drp VARCHAR2(200);
  --sql_crt VARCHAR2(200);
  row_count NUMBER;
  t_name user_tables.table_name%type;
  t_backup_name user_tables.table_name%type;
BEGIN
--   sql_drp := 'DROP TABLE :1 CASCADE';   
--   sql_crt := 'CREATE TABLE :1 AS SELECT * FROM :2';
   sql_slc := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_tables WHERE table_name = :1';
   

   OPEN c;

   LOOP
      FETCH c INTO t_name;

      EXIT WHEN (c%NOTFOUND);
      t_backup_name := t_name || '_OLD';                                        /* OLD, upper case */
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (t_name || ' ' || t_backup_name);

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_slc INTO row_count USING t_backup_name;

      IF row_count > 0
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (t_backup_name || ' dropped');

--         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_drp USING t_backup_name;
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' drop table ' || t_backup_name;                     /* concatenation and not bind variables */
      END IF;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (t_backup_name || ' created');                       /* concatenation and not bind variables */
--      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_crt USING t_backup_name, t_name;
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create table ' || t_backup_name || ' as select * from ' || t_name;

      COMMIT;
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE c;
END;
```

Also, notice that, if not double quoted, object names always are uppercase, so you have to look for `t_name || '_OLD'` and not `t_name || '_old'`